# Bad magic efbfbdef error while importing jar in bazel

Tags: java, maven, jar, bazel

I am trying to prepare maven-jar with dependencies using command,

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

I am importing this jar in bazel using `java_import`

```
java_import(
    name = "test-dependency-jars",
    jars = [
]        "deps/deps-compile/tests.jar",
    ],
)
```

While scanning this jar in bazel I get error

`Bad magic efbfbdef`

How can I resolve this error. Is there another way in which I can prepare jar with dependencies in maven, so that this error will not be seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class file inside the jar is corrupt: the file's magic value is wrong. (See  `ClassFile::magic` in the JVM documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html)

(Interestingly the first three bytes are 0xEF 0xBF 0xBD, the Unicode Replacement Character, encoded in UTF-8. I don't know what to make of that.)

Maybe you have source files in the jar, not class files? How did you build that jar?